# Bluetooth Earbuds Drop Going Between Wifi Networks?

Tags: bluetooth

I have both the AirPods Pro and the Pixelbuds. I have 2 units on my property. When I walk from one to the other, the call gets super sketchy. I assumed for a long time it was cause I was doing a wifi call and I had to blanket the whole area with a mesh. Then one day I did it, it malfunctioned, took my buds out and went to speaker and bam, immediately was working fine?

Clearly the bluetooth is getting confused when it starts to see a new network? or starts to not see the original?

After being in the new location for a few minutes it will stabilize again.

I should do a mesh but curious what the explanation for this is?

Comment: @Gantendo seems like it was on the electrical engineering SE

Comment: I'm … not sure I follow. Bluetooth devices do not "roam". They also do not have a Wi-Fi connection and they don't do phone calls. That's all your phone.

Comment: I hate SO. Why on earth was this downvoted? Because I mistakenly put it on the engineering one first?

Comment: Can’t delete it. Perfect.

Comment: Probably because it was a bit hard to understand your troubleshooting steps at first, there were even comments asking for clarification because of that. If you hate the concept of downvoting, nobody compels you to use stackexchange sites. Note that according to the help center repeated deletion of own questions can lead to your account being deleted. By deleting a question you are preventing others in the future with the same problem to find an adequate answer.

Comment: Found your comment added nothing, thanks. I am fine with downvoting as a concept. If I were designing a site I would make it have to have a rationale and a person standing behind it, not a random snipe from a faceless troll. But gee I am sure you will explain why that would be awful.

Answer (score 2):

WiFi and Bluetooth both operate on the 2,4GHz ISM band. It is well known that they sometimes interfere with each other, as well as with ZigBee and microwave ovens.

Both WiFi and Bluetooth use different techniques to try to mitigate any interference caused by other devices sending on the same frequency.

WiFi for example uses CSMA/CD (carrier sense multiple access / collision detection) and bluetooth uses channel hopping.

[This question](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/466798/does-bluetooth-interfere-with-wifi) got a few really nice answers explaining the thematic.